# Is this discouraged for HOC in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have some data in component state, that is mapped over like:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.items.map(item => {
            const enhancer = item.color = 'red' ? EnhancerA : EnhancerB
            const Enhanced = withEnhancement(enhancer)
            return <Enhanced {...item} />
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

`withEnhancement` is a `HoC` that takes either `EnhancerA` or `EnhancerB` and returns a new component.

Would this be bad practice according to the React docs over [dont use hocs inside the render method](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method) or would this be alright, as doing it inside the return statement?

Comment: "or would this be ok as I'm doing it inside the return statement?" - the `return` statement in your example is still inside the `render` method.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's pretty bad, yes... But there's a very simple workaround.

Put this code BEFORE the class declaration:

```
const EnhancedA = withEnhancement(EnhancerA);
const EnhancedB = withEnhancement(EnhancerB);
```

and inside your render function, choose which enhanced component to use:

```
const Component = item.color = 'red' ? EnhancedA : EnhancedB;
return <Component {...item} />;
```

The point of this being, you're only creating the "enhanced components" once, and reusing them inside of your `map` function, instead of creating a new component instance for every new element on your array.

Comment: or just use a [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) that will let you do these kind of stuff dynamically and not statically (like HOCs forces you to)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would be bad.

For the sake of what's discussed in the React docs you linked, they're the same thing, and this would also cause unnecessary forced rerenders.